# How can I create a two-column figure that spans across multiple pages?

Tags: floats

Within a two-column article I would like to create a figure that spans both columns and extends over more than one page. The first functionality is covered by the figure* environment. The second functionality is covered by the longfigure package. But I need to do both at the same time. How would you do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try to insert your `longtable` inside the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package.

Comment: If it covers the whole page [p] you can use \afterpage{\onecolumn...\twocolumn} (afterpage package).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `viewport` key of the [`graphicx`](http://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) package to split the big image into a desired number of subimages:

```
 \includegraphics*[viewport=<x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>]{bigImage.png}
```

with:

- `<x1>` and `<y1>` the coordinates in pixels of lower left corner
- `<x2>` and `<y2>` the coordinates in pixels of upper right corner
- `*` crop the image

  [image]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \fbox{
        \includegraphics[height=0.99\textheight]{example-image-a3.pdf}
    }
    \caption{The whole image in one page}
    \label{The whole image in one page}
    \end{figure*}
    %----------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{figure*}[h]
     \centering
      \fbox{
            \includegraphics*[viewport=0 575 400 1150]{example-image-a3.pdf}
      }
    \end{figure*}
    %
    \begin{figure*}[h]
        \centering
        \fbox{
            \includegraphics*[viewport=400 575 800 1150]{example-image-a3.pdf}
        }
    \end{figure*}
    %
    \begin{figure*}[h]
     \centering
      \fbox{
            \includegraphics*[viewport=0 0 400 575]{example-image-a3.pdf}
      }
    \end{figure*}
    %
    \begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \fbox{
            \includegraphics*[viewport=400 0 800 575]{example-image-a3.pdf}
    }
    \caption{The whole image in 4 pages}
    \label{The whole image in 4 pages}
\end{figure*}
```

And the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]